# sed | lynx | grep for remove just one <script> tag

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, server

can someone help me on that?

I have a  tag that I need to delete on a lot of files, I have the way to do that, but I can't delete just that one specific script. Below is the commands that I have:

```
grep -l "location.lowerbeforwarde" /home/servidorpromover/public_html/pastaTudo/*/wp-content/themes/*/functions.php | xargs sed -i 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

But if I use this command, it will delete all the  tags in the server, and I want just delete the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/some.JS.file.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If it not clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you post small input and output file that will clarify the text to be removed, and the text to be kept ?

Comment: Are you trying to delete all <script> tags, or just the <scripts> that refer to a specific Javascript  file ?

Comment: Try `sed 's#<script.*script>##g'`

Comment: Just a single one script, a Specific script